# Apache not authorized to read NFS mount

Tags: apache-http-server, nfs

A folder is mounted on a web server (Apache) with NFS but this server can't see the folder.
I can see the folder but Apache cannot:

```
Starting httpd: Warning: DocumentRoot [/mount folder/.../] does not exist
Warning: DocumentRoot [/mount folder/.../] does not exist
```

NFS config `/etc/export`

```
/folder          192.168.x.x(rw,subtree_check,all_squash)
```

On client `/etc/fstab`

```
192.168.x.x:folder/ /folder nfs rw  0   0
```

Answer (score 8):

Easier way then taking away SELinux protection is simply to allow use of NFS to it:

```
setsebool httpd_use_nfs on
```

Answer (score -1):

I found solution !

In the web server, edit /etc/sysconfig/selinux and disable this.

```
SELINUX=disabled
```

Comment: That compares closely to 'I have problems with lock, so I removed the lock. Things do now work'.  They do, but please realize that you just disabled a security feature that was enabled by default for a reason.